# TouchEvent not working in firefox and other website browser

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a problem, in chrome it runs well, but it won't fire in firefox

```
function normalizeEvent(e){     
  if(e.originalEvent instanceof TouchList){
    do somethings    
   }
}
```

and here is message error: ReferenceError: TouchEvent is not defined

```
if(e.originalEvent instanceof TouchEvent){}
```

Answer (score 20):

To get this work in FF, just add `window.TouchEvent` condition (is it defined):

`if(window.TouchEvent && e.originalEvent instanceof TouchEvent){}`

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that Firefox on mobile *does* have `TouchEvent`, so it's safe-ish to assume you're not dealing with a touch capable device if it is undefined. Not sure if it's defined if you use Firefox on a touch-capable desktop.